# Evaluation of the integral $\int_0^1 e^{2t^2 -at} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, signal-processing

I would like to integrate a function in the range $[0,1]$. I tried a lot of ways including Mathlab. All solutions come in terms of some error function.

I would like the answer in terms of $a$.

$$\int_0^1 e^{2t^2 -at} dt$$

Comment: Not possible. No closed form in terms of elementary functions for that integral.

Answer (score 1):

> *All solutions come in terms of some [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). I would like the answer in terms of a*.

Since those error functions had *a* in their argument, you already got what you wanted.